# Calling an angularjs factory module from the Controller Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a question regarding the AngularJS Factory module. It throws me this error:[$injector:undef]

This is my test-Factory returning a simple object

```js
angular.module('myModel', []).factory('test', function(){
    var testObject = {myname: 'Jan'};
    var factory = {};
    factory.getTestObject = function() {
        return testObject;
    }
});
```

This is is the controller Module where I would like to call the factory

```js
angular.module('LoginController', [])
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, test) {

    $scope.tagline = 'Facebook Login';


});
```

This is  the main module injection

```js
angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'LoginController', 'Ctrl2', 'myModel']);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a new module for the controller, you can use the existing module,

```
angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'Ctrl2', 'myModel'])
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, test) {    
    $scope.tagline = 'Facebook Login';    

});
```

Otherwise you need to inject the myModel to your **`LoginController`** module

```
angular.module('LoginController', [ 'myModel'])
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, test) {
    $scope.tagline = 'Facebook Login';

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried your second suggestion, injecting it in the LoginController Module, but it throws me the same error.

[$injector:undef] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/undef?p0=test
http://localhost:3333/libs/angular/angular.min.js:6 – "<div ng-view=\"\" class=\"ng-scope\">"

Comment: Sorry for waisting your time, I forgot to return the factory object in the factory module therefore it threw the undefined error. Thanks for helping me out though, I just got started with angularJs